# Redis RPUSH with multiple values recommandations

Tags: redis

I have millions of lines to push in a Redis list.
For now, I send them one line after one other with `rpush` and an unique value.

I've seen in the doc that we can send multiple values.

1. Is this faster ?
2. How many items can I send in one `rpush` ?

The purpose is to be the most efficient of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this faster ?

Of course, it will be faster. Since you can reduce lots of `RTT`.

> How many items can I send in one rpush ?

Technically, you can send `2^31 - 1` (`INT_MAX`) items in one `RPUSH`. However, it's always a bad idea to send too many items in a single command. Because that would block Redis for a long time, and you should make a trade-off.

Do some benchmark, and make a reasonable batch size.

Comment: Up to a few hundreds (depending on the value size as well) is a good ballpark. On top of using variadic pushes, you can get an additional kicking by pipeline them.